# How to fit image set full screen in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am trying to display an image from a web url using WKWebView.
Can not resize the webView content.

```
 let url = URL(string: url)
 let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
 web.navigationDelegate = self as! WKNavigationDelegate
 web.load(request)
```

Comment: See WKWebView's properties.

Answer (score 0):

To resize the content of WKWebView to fit your device you need to inject JavaScript to be executed after the page is loaded, that will set the `width` attribute to `device-width`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48905225/force-html-content-to-fit-in-device-width-with-wkwebview)

Comment: "you need to inject JavaScript to be executed after the page is loaded"  Que?

Comment: The 'webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) ' is not working. Then can not identified when webView is loaded.